# How can I write a function of the following form in Coq?

Tags: coq, termination, totality

```
f x = f (g subtermOfX)
```

Is recursion only allowed if the arg to the function is a direct subterm of the arg passed so that Coq can see that it actually terminates?

Comment: I think this question is actually two questions. Could you please separate them?

Comment: @AntonTrunov could you please look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47951686/how-can-i-make-coq-accept-the-following-fixpoint ?

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to write such function `f` if function `g` preserves the property of being a subterm.

Some of the standard functions have this property, e.g. `pred`, `sub`:

```
From Coq Require Import Arith List.
Import ListNotations.

Fixpoint foo (x : nat) : nat :=
  match x with
  | O => 42
  | S x' => foo (pred x'). (* foo (x' - 1) works too *)
  end.
```

On the other hand some (standard) functions do not have this property, but can be rewritten to remedy this deficiency. E.g. the standard `tl` function does not preserve the subterm property, so the following fails:

```
Fail Fixpoint bar (xs : list nat) : list nat :=
  match xs with
  | [] => []
  | x :: xs' => bar (tl xs')
  end.
```

but if we redefine the tail function like so

```
Fixpoint new_tl {A : Type} (xs : list A) :=
  match xs with
  | [] => xs           (* `tl` returns `[]` here *) 
  | _ :: xs' => xs'
  end.
```

we can recover the desired property:

```
Fixpoint bar (xs : list nat) : list nat :=
  match xs with
  | [] => []
  | x :: xs' => bar (new_tl xs')
  end.
```

The only difference between `tl` and `new_tl` is that in the case of empty input list `tl` returns `[]`, but `new_tl` returns the original list.